# <div> inside <tr> to regroup two <td>

Tags: jquery, html-table

I need to regroup two td under one id.

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <div id="a1">
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </div>
    <div id="a2">
    </div>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I need this to do jQuery operation on two td at once. Is it possible? Is there another solution to do this?

Comment: This markup is invalid. Within a `tr` you can have just `td` or `th`. Add a class to the `tds` to be grouped.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? There is likely to be a better solution as this would be invalid HTML (see Permitted Content at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/tr).

Comment: Try to use `CSS` tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have a `div` as a child of a `tr`. Use `class` or `data-` attributes instead:

```
<table>
  <tr>
      <td data-group="1" class="group group1"></td>
      <td data-group="1" class="group group1"></td>
      <td data-group="2" class="group group2"></td>
      <td data-group="3" class="group group3"></td>
      <td data-group="4" class="group group4"></td>
      <td data-group="4" class="group group4"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be simpler, and valid HTML:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="a1"></td>
    <td class="a1"></td>
    <td class="a2"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: And, as @MelanciaUK said, it can be referenced by `$("td.a1")` or `$("td.a2")`

Answer (score 1):

As I said in the comments, this markup is invalid. Within a `tr` you can have just `td` or `th`. Add a class to the `tds` to be grouped:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="a1"></td>
        <td class="a1"></td>
        <td class="a2"></td>
        <td class="a2"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

And on jQuery you can use the following selectors:

```
$("td.a1")

$("td.a2")
```